# Return a default value if no rows are found in UNION ALL query

Tags: mysql, join

## Scenario

I have a query developed from this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77466/optimise-web-panel-users-statistics-query), were part of the optimisation was to create a MySql view which is used for generating statistics for users and sales, the problem is that when there is no result for one of the `SELECT` rows it gets omitted from the resulting table.

### Question

How can a tell MySql to set a default value (e.g 0) if no rows are found for any of the `SELECT`?

### Code

This is the code for creating the view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_events AS
    SELECT 'Complete profiles' AS type, created_at
        FROM users
        WHERE completed_registration = 1

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Incomplete profiles', created_at
        FROM users
        WHERE completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Unverified profiles', created_at
        FROM users
        WHERE verified_email = 0

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Onsite Teachers', created_at
        FROM onsite_teachers

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Onsite Teachers hired', created_at
        FROM purchases
            INNER JOIN purchased_profiles
                ON purchased_profiles.purchase_id = purchases.id
                 AND purchased_profiles.profile_type = 'onsite_teacher'
        WHERE purchases.transaction_status = 'completed'

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Translators', created_at
        FROM translators

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Translators hired', created_at
        FROM purchases
            INNER JOIN purchased_profiles
                ON purchased_profiles.purchase_id = purchases.id
                AND purchased_profiles.profile_type = 'translator'
        WHERE purchases.transaction_status = 'completed'

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Interpreters', created_at
        FROM interpreters

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Interpreters hired', created_at
        FROM purchases
            INNER JOIN purchased_profiles
                ON purchased_profiles.purchase_id = purchases.id
                AND purchased_profiles.profile_type = 'interpreter'
        WHERE purchases.transaction_status = 'completed';
```

And this is the code for querying the totals for the last 6 months including the current month.

```
SELECT 
    type, 
    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN created_at >= CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY AS DATETIME) 
        THEN 1 
    END) AS 0_month_ago, 

    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN created_at BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS DATETIME)
            AND CAST(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATETIME)
        THEN 1 
    END) AS 1_month_ago,

    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN created_at BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AS DATETIME)
            AND CAST(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATETIME)
        THEN 1 
    END) AS 2_months_ago,

    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN created_at BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AS DATETIME)
            AND CAST(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATETIME)
        THEN 1 
    END) AS 3_months_ago,

    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN created_at BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 4 MONTH AS DATETIME)
            AND CAST(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATETIME)
        THEN 1 
    END) AS 4_months_ago,

    COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN created_at BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 5 MONTH AS DATETIME)
            AND CAST(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATETIME)
        THEN 1 
    END) AS 5_months_ago
FROM 
    user_events
GROUP BY 
    type;
```

### Current output

If you look closely there is no `Interpreters hired` and `Translators hired` rows, I want for this rows to be set and zeroed out if they return `null`

```
+=========================+===============+===============+===============+==============+===============+===============+
|          type           |  0_month_ago  |  1_month_ago  |  2_month_ago  | 3_month_ago  |  4_month_ago  |  5_month_ago  |
+=========================+===============+===============+===============+==============+===============+===============+
|    Complete profiles    |       7       |      20       |      14       |      25      |      30       |       7       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Incomplete profiles   |      12       |      27       |      56       |      45      |      48       |      23       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Unverified profiles   |       3       |      16       |      23       |       5      |       0       |       9       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|    Onsite Teachers      |      11       |      36       |       8       |      15      |      46       |      12       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|  Onsite Teachers hired  |       0       |       0       |      12       |       9      |       3       |       0       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|      Interpreters       |       4       |      21       |      27       |      46      |      45       |      28       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|      Translators        |       7       |      20       |      19       |      27      |      19       |      42       |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_events` view is a kind of a log, which looks like

```
type                  | created_at
======================+==============
Interpreters hired    | 2014-12-12
Interpreters hired    | 2014-12-14
Interpreters hired    | 2014-12-16
Interpreters hired    | 2015-01-02
```

However, if no interpreter has ever been hired, then there will be no rows with `type = 'Interpreters hired'`.  In that case, the counting query cannot possibly fabricate an `Interpreters hired`  row out of thin air.

A solution is to ensure that an `Interpreters hired` row appears in the `user_events` view, no matter what.  You could create such fictitious rows with no `created_at` date.  That way, there will always be something to `GROUP BY`, but not necessarily anything to `COUNT()`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_events AS
    SELECT 'Complete profiles' AS type, created_at
        FROM users
        WHERE completed_registration = 1

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Incomplete profiles', created_at
        FROM users
        WHERE completed_registration = 0 AND verified_email = 1

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Unverified profiles', created_at
        FROM users
        WHERE verified_email = 0

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Onsite Teachers', created_at
        FROM onsite_teachers

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Onsite Teachers hired', created_at
        FROM purchases
            INNER JOIN purchased_profiles
                ON purchased_profiles.purchase_id = purchases.id
                 AND purchased_profiles.profile_type = 'onsite_teacher'
        WHERE purchases.transaction_status = 'completed'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Onsite Teachers hired', NULL

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Translators', created_at
        FROM translators

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Translators hired', created_at
        FROM purchases
            INNER JOIN purchased_profiles
                ON purchased_profiles.purchase_id = purchases.id
                AND purchased_profiles.profile_type = 'translator'
        WHERE purchases.transaction_status = 'completed'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Translators hired', NULL

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Interpreters', created_at
        FROM interpreters

    UNION ALL SELECT 'Interpreters hired', created_at
        FROM purchases
            INNER JOIN purchased_profiles
                ON purchased_profiles.purchase_id = purchases.id
                AND purchased_profiles.profile_type = 'interpreter'
        WHERE purchases.transaction_status = 'completed'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Interpreters hired', NULL;
```